# Итератор Java в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, итераторы

Есть код на Java:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> dc = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) request.getAttribute("DC");
  Iterator<HashMap<String, String>> dcIt = dc.iterator();
  while (dcIt.hasNext()) {
    HashMap<String, String> dcEntry = dcIt.next(); //код 
}
```

Мне нужно переписать логику на JS.
Как итератор переписать на JS?

Comment: Что делает итератор?

Answer (score 2):

В новой спецификации `js` есть такое понятие как итераторы 
 
Для того что бы ваш объект умел в итераторы, нужно добавить ему специальный метод `Symbol.iterator`

```
'use strict';

const range = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5
}

// сделаем объект range итерируемым
range[Symbol.iterator] = function() {

  let current = this.from;
  const last = this.to;

  // метод должен вернуть объект с методом next()
  return {
    next() {
      if (current <= last) {
        return {
          done: false,
          value: current++
        };
      } else {
        return {
          done: true
        };
      }
    }

  }
};

for (let num of range) {
  alert(num); // 1, затем 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

[Почитать подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/iterator)

Comment: `const current = this.from;` и `value: current++` ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych мы используем замыкание, что бы не мутировать само поле `this.from`

Comment: та я про конст и его изминение...

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych спасибо, поправил

Comment: Почему вы решили вынести создание метода в отдельный оператор присваивания? Можно же просто написать `[Symbol.iterator]() { ... }` внутри литерала объекта

Answer (score 1):

Список превращается в массив, а словарь со строковыми ключами - в простой объект. Только объекты для словарей рекомендуется создавать через `Object.create(null)` в случае, если он поддерживается браузером.

```js
var dcs = [{x: "a"}, {x: "b", y: "qqq", "мой ключ": "значение"}];

for (var dc of dcs) {
  for (var key of Object.keys(dc)) {
    console.log(`${key} => ${dc[key]}`);
  }

  console.log("===");
}
```